# Excel VSTO, set different color to locked cells in protected sheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am writing a C# VSTO for Excel.
One of the features in to protect a worksheet, but to leave some cells unlocked for editing.
For the protection of the sheet, I am using the following code:

```
_Worksheet ws = WP.Application.ActiveSheet;
ws.Protect(null, true, true, true, AllowFormattingCells: true);
```

Before the sheet was protected, the user was able to set some of the cells Unlocked using the Excel UI as shown in the picture.
[image: Unlocked cells]

I am looking for a way to set foreground color of the unlocked cells after the sheet has been protected.
The code I have so far is iterating the UsedRange and checking each cell:

```
foreach (Range cell in ws.UsedRange)
{
    if (!cell.Locked)
    {
        cell.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Bisque);
    }
}
```

I know that this is not efficient. Is there a more way to query excel regarding the Locked state of the range?

Comment: How did you get the list of cells you had to leave unlocked? You could use that very same source.

Comment: The user selected the range that needs to be unlocked. I dont have a control on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast method for determining unlocked cell range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387443/fast-method-for-determining-unlocked-cell-range)

Comment: You can use a macro recorder available in Excel to get a VBA code generated for you automatically. That way you can find the required sequence of property and method calls.